# Encoding on clicked href URI breaks path

Tags: html, onenote, location-href

On my intranet web app I serve the users a link to OneNote book on public folder. It magically works even if browsers do not allow to load local resources.
However I get the error opening resources with special characters in the URI.

Here is the link if I hoover over `<a>` tag:
`onenote:\\\\company.local\folder\OneNoteWithChar_š.one`
When I click on the link I get the error saying:

> We couldn't open that location. It might not exist or you might not have permission to open it ... `onenote:\\\\company.local\folder\OneNoteWithChar_%C5%BE.one`

When I try to open files without this 'special' char (it is not special in our language, also it is allowed in Windows file and folder naming, the note opens normally.

How to avoid encoding of URI when clicked on it?

Comment: I think that this is impossible, web browsers convert special characters to the percent thing... There shouldn't be a problem with it though... are you sure the file location is correct?

Comment: Yes, this happens only when there are 'š','č' or 'ž' in filename. URI is generated by server when file is created, so it "must" be correct.

Comment: I tested it now on my local drive. Files containing 'š', 'č' and 'ž' fail to open.

Comment: Is it possible, that OneNote treats encoded char as two separate chars, because for example ```Ž``` is URL decoded: ```%C5%BD``` which is also: ```Å½```